# Change color of Custom marker on Map in Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I'm trying to change the color of markers on Map. I want shape of a common marker but with custom colors. I've tried the following code but it doesn't make any change in color and doesn't give any error as well. Can you please guide any solution or any alternative approach? Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Code:**

```
Drawable background = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pink_map);
    if (background instanceof ShapeDrawable) {
        ((ShapeDrawable)background).getPaint().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.theme_color));
    } else if (background instanceof GradientDrawable) {
        ((GradientDrawable)background).setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.theme_color));
    }

    // convert drawable to bitmap
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) background).getBitmap();

    Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
                    .title("My Location")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap))
```

Answer (score 4):

This is working for me:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(contactLatLng)
                    .title(contactName)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_map_blue))
                    );
```

The important thing is to import the image asset as 'Action Bar and Tab Icons' option. Then you choose the theme CUSTOM and you can select a custom color to apply your image.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

please try this code

```
  BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptor
            = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(
            (int) BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE);

     mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(sydney)
            .title("My Location")
            .snippet("and snippet")
            .icon(bitmapDescriptor);
```

if it doesn't works please check this alternative library from [GDC](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/)

Comment: I want to use custom marker, not the default. By using the code that i have posted am able to change the get expected results when i change resource of a view (i.e. ImageButton) but when I apply it to marker , it doesn't change in the color.